# Descargar archivo CSV con FileZilla y MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

Quiero descargar un archivo CSV creado desde una consulta desde mySQL. Quiero usar FileZilla pero no sé como hacerlo, alguien que me apoye? Tengo este código.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLEADOS
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Pero no quiero ponerla en mi "C:\" si no en el C:\ de la persona que haya invocado la función.
Me pueden apoyar con la configuración? Uso XAMPP

Comment: A que refieres al decir Quiero usar FileZilla? filezilla es un cliente ftp, que depende de lo que las acciones que lleve acabo el usuario con el mismo.

Comment: Pues a que del servidor, se puedan descargar exportes de MySQL en la máquina del usuario que hizo la invocación. "Click"

Comment: Si lo que buscas es que al hacer `click` el usuario pueda descargar el `csv`, yo te recomiendo que re-formules tu pregunta, omitiendo la palabra FileZilla, o reemplazandola, por ejemplo, con "PHP" (ya que estas usando XAMPP). Solo así vas a obtener una respuesta. Como esta hecha actualmente pareciera que intentas hacer algo un tanto "rebuscado"

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando una petición al servidor, no puedes invocar a un cliente ftp de esa manera y no debes ingresar a los datos o directorios del usuario sin antes pedir permiso al mismo, si estás trabajando con un sitio web y lo que deseas es generar un CSV y luego descargarlo en un clic lo que puedes hacer es llamar a tu función mysql desde PHP y que el archivo se genere en la ruta del servidor, para que al final quede algo así: http://localhost:8000/files/csv/micsv.csv y realizar un evento clic en un botón con HTML para llamar a dicha ubicación que bien puedes traer mediante ajax o alguna otra forma, pero como te menciono, ésto es sólo si estas trabajando con web, pero no puedes llamar al cliente ftp desde una consulta de MySQL para hacerle descargar un archivo, saludos!